# Ruby on Rails 6. Using Ajax after redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari

Say, I have users list on the '/users' page and 2 actions for the 'user' entity: '**index**' (with using of Ajax) and '**destroy**'.

```
  def index
      ...    
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
  end

  def destroy
    ...    
    redirect_to users_url
  end
```

I want to destroy a user (right from the '/users' page) and use Ajax of the '**index**' action after that ('**index.js.erb**' file) in order to render only a part of the opened '/users' page.

**Is it possible to do that?**

---

My current solution right now is to use Ajax for 'destroy' action (a separate 'destroy.js.erb' file) and duplicate needed changes for 'index' page there. But, first of all, it's a code duplication, and second, in this case my pagination links are broken (I use 'Kaminari' gem and looks like it works fine only with 'get' requests, at least by default).

---

There is a 'view' part of updating with Ajax, if necessary:

```
   <div id="users_table">     
      <table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
        ...
        <tbody>
          <%= render @users %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    
      <div><%= paginate @users, remote: true %></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please include your view code for destroy and index.

Comment: I'v added a 'view' part that's updated with Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the destroy action to render the index.js.erb:

```
def destroy
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render action: :index}
    format.html { redirect_to users_url}
  end
end
```

But, to render index.js you will need to, in your destroy action, rebuild the `@users` object and ensure you're rebuilding it for the correct page. So, when you call the destroy action you'll need to pass the ID(s) of the user(s) you want to destroy, as well as the page you are on.

Comment: If you post The full `index` and `destroy` actions code from your controller I can help more with my warnings around recreating @users

Comment: Yed, rendering 'index' works fine, but it doesn't solve the pagination issue I faced to. Pagination 'href' changed  in accordance with used method (again, the link to this issue: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/issues/1030). That is, for 'delete' action the pagination link to the 2nd page changes from "/users?page=2" to "/users/25?page=2". What's why I started thinking about redirection option. I don't know what else can I do here... maybe I can change this URL somehow? I've tried to change route for that (delete  '/users/:id', to: 'users#index'), but it doesn't work...

Comment: Anyway, thanks @tom for trying to help me, I really appreciate that!

Comment: Post the full code of the index and destroy actions along with the index.html.erb, index.js.erb and destroy.js.erb

Comment: I've found the solution with pagination. It turned out that Kaminary allows to specify controller and action via 'params' hash. So I had to change only one thing in my view: <%= paginate @users, params: {controller: "users", action: "index"}, remote: true %>

Comment: Anyway, your solution with rendeting 'index' was pretty much close to my initial question. Thanks a lot, @tom. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your destroy.js.erb should (on successful destruction) remove the destroyed element from the index by deleting a part of the HTML. I don’t expect that the code to do that duplicates the code you have in the index view.

Post your current destroy.js.erb as well as the relevant part of index.html.erb for more help though.

You can also use redirect within a respond_to so your HTML call will redirect while the Ajax uses destroy.js.erb

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html { redirect_to users_url}
```

You could also hack your way to your answer by calling `render :index` for the js response. But, if you were to try to render the index view here you’ll definitely get duplication of code, along with an extra DB call and probably some broken pagination. So, I’d recommend that you take the approach I first suggested (use destroy.js.erb to remove that user from the HTML)

Finally, more generally, when you’re trying to avoid duplication of view code; a partial might be the answer

Comment: Yes, actually this is my current approach in terms of 'destroy' action. And everything works fine except pagination (more details here: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/issues/1030). That's why I'm trying to find another solution, using redirection to 'index' (in order to use 'get' request), but I can't get how I can use 'index' Ajax this way.

Comment: The 'destroy.js.erb' file is a pretty straightforward: $("#users_table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users_table')) %>");

Comment: With the approach I’m suggesting, your destroy.js.erb file would look more like `$(“tr#user-<%= @user.id %>”).hide()`. Something which hides (or greys out, or somehow represents deletion of) the row which had the now deleted user data.

Comment: Can you include the code from the view partial which renders each user row in the table?

Comment: Well, I definitely need to update the whole list, because we also talk about a multiple selection and deletion. So, I need to re-render the whole list with pagination links accordingly.

Comment: But what about the redirection approach? Is it possible to use Ajax of the 'index' action after that? If yes, it can solve my issue with pagination, I gues.

Comment: I’ve added that approach in a new answer. That will reduce duplication of view code; but not sure it’ll fix your pagination issue